# algorithm for traversing multiple tables for a query

Tags: sql, algorithm, tree, tree-traversal, graph-traversal

I am trying to write an algorithm which will help me to find the best path through multiple tables to fetch data for a query.  The tables have overlapping variables which relate them to each other.  For example, I may have a query like this:

'select T1:F1 such that T3:F6 > 0'

The tables are set up like this:

Table1 (T1):
F1, F2

Table 2 (T2):
F2, F3, F4

Table 3 (T3):
F4, F5, F6

where there are values assigned for the entries of F1 through F6.  Thus, Table 1 has F1, and F2 is its brother.  F2 is also in Table 2, and F4 is also its brother.  F4 is also in Table 3, and F6 is its brother.

The correct way for traversing through the tables would be:
T1:F1 -> T1:F2 -> T2:F2 -> T2:F4 -> T3:F4 -> T3:F6

is there an algorithm for doing this?  It seems like it would be too hard to simply search through the brothers of each table.  seems like it would be some sort of tree search algorithm but I can't figure out how to set up the tree.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with relational databases, it is better to think in terms of what you want instead of how to do it (algorithm). In this case, what you want is:

```
select     T1.F1
from       T1 
inner join T2 on T1.F2 = T2.F2
inner join T3 on T2.F4 = T3.F4
where      T3.F6 > 0
```

Comment: ok thanks!  however, the thing I want to do is to be able to go from T1.F1 to T3.F6 without having know about T1.F2, T2.F2, T2.F4, and T3.F4.  there may be more than one path through the tables to get from T1.F1 to T3.F6.  It seems like there should be a tree traversal algorithm to do this, but I can't quite formulate the problem in terms of a tree.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make sense of what you want. What do you mean by "go from T1.F1 to T3.F6"? Why do you talk about trees? please provide concrete data and an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: well, the tables are related to each other through the common fields that they have.  so Table1 and Table2 have F2 in common, and Table2 and Table3 have F4 in common.  The data in each of the fields like F1 and F2 could be related.  For example, F1 could be name, and F2 could be age.  F1 and F2 are on the same table, so it's the first part of the path.  (T1:F1 -> T1:F2).  The next part of the path is (T1:F2 -> T2:F2), since they are related to each other.  Then it's (T2:F4 -> T3:F4).  The last part is (T3:F4 -> T3:F6).  I'm not sure about using a tree right now.